# How to navigate in second prompt in python

Tags: python, shell, command-line

In a python shell I am defining a function. Now I made a mistake, and would like to jump up 4 lines to edit this statement: `for i in range(N):`

```
>>> def bisect(a,b,N):
...     for i in range(N):
...             num = f((a-b)/2.0)
...             if num == 0:
...                     print (a-b)/2.0
...             elif ()
```

How can I navigate up and down the shell to make modifications?

Comment: use ipython! it is awesome

Comment: I had never heard of ipython. It does indeed look very cool - thanks! But, I don't know, why not just save your code in a file and run it from there? Edit, test, repeat. => Well, I guess an uber-interactive shell like that *would* be pretty nice for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Use another Python shell like IPython, for example.

The Qt console for IPython (`ipython qtconsole`) or the IPython Notebook offer the feature you want. You can just navigate in the code using the arrow keys while writing it.

Comment: Now that I downloaded IPython, what is the hotkey to navigate to the previous line? Thanks.M

Comment: Sorry I was not so precise in my answer so I just edited it. With raw IPython, you can't exactly do what you want neither; give a try to the qtconsole it's really nice.